# Read string in an array and convert it to array in Smalltalk

Tags: arrays, oop, object, smalltalk

I am trying to read a text file which contains sets of words and convert them to a collection. What I did first is that I grouped the words by separating them whenever there is a carriage return. I successfully stored it inside an array. The next thing that I wanted to do is to read the string array contents and group the words again by separating them into an array inside the array. Is it possible? Hope you could help me out. Thanks!

I tried to do loop the current collection and place some conditions that would trim whitespaces and put them in a new collection inside the array but it's not working.

Here's what I've done so far:

Syntax:

```
| fileName fileRead values |
fileName := 'fruitVendor.txt'.
fileRead := fileName asFilename readStream.
fileValues := OrderedCollection new.
arrValues := OrderedCollection new.
[(string := fileRead upTo: Core.Character cr) isEmpty]
    whileFalse: [fileValues addLast: string].
param := fileValues asArray.
param do: 
        [:ea |
        stream := ReadStream on: ea.
        [(arrString := stream upTo: Core.Character space) isEmpty]
            whileFalse: [arrValues addLast: arrString].]
```

Here's the content of the file:

`fruitVendor.txt`

```
China     Beijing     Apple  //cr
Hawaii    Honolulu    Pineapple   //cr
Japan     Tokyo       Banana //cr
Vietnam   Ho chi min  Pear
```

the output should be:

```
#(#('China' 'Beijing' 'Apple')#('Hawaii' 'Honolulu' ''Pineapple)#('Japan' 'Tokyo' 'Banana')#('Vietnam' 'Ho chi min' 'Pear'))
```

What I'm trying to achieve:

To store the string inside the array into a new array inside the array itself, more like a byte array.

Comment: The only issue I see is that you forgot to `close` the file stream  `fileRead`. By the way, what's your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to turn each element (the line String) of your first collection into a different element (Array of words) based on the original. That is the purpose of the `collect:` message for Collections.

```
arrValues := fileValues collect: 
    [:each | | inner |
    inner := OrderedCollection new.
    stream := ReadStream on: each.
    [(word := stream upTo: Core.Character space) isEmpty]
        whileFalse: [inner addLast: word].
    inner asArray "<-- this is the answer value of this block"]
```

Note that depending on your Smalltalk dialect, there may be some kind of split method in String.

Comment: I think you would face the issue of 'Ho chi min' which is a city split by spaces.

Answer (score 3):

I took the liberty to do it more "smalltalk" way as @JayK showed you the more generic way (it does not deal with the issue of `'Ho chi min'`).

All my examples are using [`Smalltalk/X-jv`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/smalltalkx/info).  I'll try to do it the natural way, how one would think of such an issue.

The first thing that comes into mind is to "just" split it via space (one space `Character space`).  Three is such a handy selector called `#splitBy:` and `#splitByAll:` for the second example.

So we try it with:

```
| readFileStream citiesCollection |

readFileStream := 'C:\t\so\smalltalk\fruitVendor_space.txt' asFilename readStream.
citiesCollection := OrderedCollection new.

readFileStream linesDo: [ :eachLine |
    | cities |
    cities := (eachLine splitBy: Character space) select: [ :eachCity | eachCity notEmpty ].   
    citiesCollection add: cities asArray
].

citiesCollection inspect
```

The result is probably not what you expected, because the last Array is:

`#('Vietnam' 'Ho' 'chi' 'min' 'Pear')`

This is due a fact you have a space in string `'Ho chi min'` city.

Is there a way to deal with it?  In your scenario there is.  Lets split it by using **two** spaces instead of just **one**:

```
| readFileStream citiesCollection spitCollection |

readFileStream := 'C:\t\so\smalltalk\fruitVendor_space.txt' asFilename readStream.
citiesCollection := OrderedCollection new.
spitCollection := OrderedCollection new.
2 timesRepeat: [ spitCollection add: (Character space) ]. "/ adding two spaces

readFileStream linesDo: [ :eachLine |
    | cities |
    cities := (eachLine splitByAll: spitCollection) select: [ :eachCity | eachCity notEmpty ].
    cities := cities copy collect: [ :eachCity | eachCity withoutSpaces ].
    citiesCollection add: cities asArray
].

citiesCollection inspect.
```

Now we get a correct result for the `'Ho chi min'` city string.

`#('Vietnam' 'Ho chi min' 'Pear')`

That all being said I think the most preferable way (in real life) is to make the split at the source file by using some kind of splitter like `$;` (`;` character) - like `csv` file but with `;`. (Nobody said that in the future you will have two spaces to split it by - so you need to have a splitter which will define end of the string - that is probably main reason why csv came to being).

The source file would be:

```
China;    Beijing;    Apple;
Hawaii;   Honolulu;   Pineapple;
Japan;    Tokyo;      Banana;
Vietnam;  Ho chi min; Pear;
```

Then the code would look similar to the first code above:

```
| readFileStream citiesCollection |

readFileStream := 'C:\t\so\smalltalk\fruitVendor.txt' asFilename readStream.
citiesCollection := OrderedCollection new.

readFileStream linesDo: [ :eachLine |
    | cities |
    cities := (eachLine splitBy: $;) collect: [ :eachCity | eachCity withoutSpaces ].
    citiesCollection add: cities asArray
].

citiesCollection inspect.
```